# In survival analysis, how to calculate power from hazard ratio and number of events given alpha?

Tags: survival, sample-size, statistical-power

If I know number of events and hazard ratio, with given alpha, how do I calculate the power?

Answer (score 0):

`z<-0.5*sqrt(n)*log(1/hr)-qnorm(1-alpha/2)
power<-pnorm(z)`

Comment: See the `cpower` and `spower` functions in the R `Hmisc` package.